# Issue when checking if key exist in array and setting a new value with variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to check if key exists in array and change it if it does, or add if does not. I need to do it without jQuery.
I store the array in cookies stringified.

```
if (item_id in items) items[item_id] = count;
else
{
    var tmp = {};
    tmp[item_id] = count;
    items.push(tmp);
}
```

`item_id` and `count` are always numbers. The problem is when I check if key exists it checks the number of element in array. For example, if I have pair `[{1:5},{5,3}]` and check if key 5 exists if returns false, if I check for key 1 it returns true and changes the array like that `[{1:5},new_value]`

I tried `if (item_id in items)`, `if (items[item_id])`, didn't work. How should I make it work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Simple Fix***

`items` is a regular JS array, not an associative array. You will have to loop and check `item_id` against each object, as shown below. If it is not found anywhere in the list, after looping, then add it to the list (as your original `else` was doing):

```
var found = false;

for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (item_id in items[i]) {
        items[i][item_id] = count;
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!found)
{
    var tmp = {};
    tmp[item_id] = count;
    items.push(tmp);
}
```

---

***More complete solution***

Note, some of the difficulty you may be having might be due to the unusual data structure you have chosen, and you might choose to structure your data differently for easier lookup and retrieval. Right now you have a list of unrelated pairs, `[{key1 : value1}, {key2: value2}, ...]` when you really want a dictionary (hash map) like `{ key1: value1, key2: value2, ...}`.

If you use that updated structure, your code would look more like your original:

```
if (item_id in items) items[item_id] += count;
else
{
    items[item_id] = count;
}
```

(I assume you actually want to increment the `count` if it already exists, rather than overwriting it. This assumes an associative array (dictionary) as your data structure.)

Comment: I was just about to confirm that! nbrooks is right, you'll have to loop and check each item.

Comment: I tried using `items[item_id] = count;` instead of checking every time if key exists and changing, but I get `[{null,value}]` all the time. I got advices to use push, as I do now. I don't need to increment, I need overwrite)

Comment: @user3145700 When you initialize `items`, if you're using it as an associative array, you would say `var items = {}`. That creates a dictionary, which does not have a `push` method at all. If you do `var items = []`, you are creating an array, which gives you entirely different functionality, which I don't think you want. Note the difference in bracket style.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are my savior!) I will use `items = {}`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
array.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex]);
```

In case you can use jQuery it has a utility function for this.

```
$.inArray(value, array)
```

Comment: This won't work for the same reason the OP's code didn't work - the key they want to search by isn't an element in the array, it's a property name of an object that is an element in the array.